# Problems With TD Onclick

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have made a few tables before but this one doesn't work. I have gave half of the Td's of this table onclick functions. From There i add different values to variable x. I then ask to show x. The result I am getting is the same as if nothing was there at all.

Here is the code

```
//Part 1
<td onclick="Score()">

//Part 2
<script>
    var x = 0
    function Score() {
        x += 92
    }
    //Part 3
    {
        document.write(x);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some syntax error and Block error on your code!

Try this:

```
//Part 1
<td onclick="Score()">

//Part 2
<script>
    var x = 0;
    function Score() {
        x += 92;
        document.write(x);
    }
</script>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxojyt9r/)

Comment: I know - The content of the website is a little private so I rewrote it so that would be the formatting error.

Comment: Can you fix the problem?

Comment: It works fine for me. View it on fiddle I have append to answer

Comment: I am sorry i dont understand the second part of your comment